# invalid Blocktype on Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter

Tags: magento-1.9, error, ce-1.9.1.0, email-templates, order-confirmation

I'm running Magento CE 1.9.1.0 with Firegento GermanSetup.
When completing a order, no order confirmations via email are sent instead I get this error stack:

```
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Ungültiger Blocktyp: Mage_Germansetup_Block_Imprint_Content' in /var/www/my-project-de/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/my-project-de/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Ung??ltiger Blo...')
#1 /var/www/my-project-de/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('germansetup/imp...', Array)
#2 /var/www/my-project-de/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php(169): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('germansetup/imp...', NULL, Array)
#3 [internal function]: Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter->blockDirective(Array)
#4 /var/www/my-project-de/lib/Varien/Filter/Template.php(163): call_user_func(Array, Array)
#5 /var/www/my-project-de/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php(548): Varien_Filter_Template->filter('????<body style...')
#6 /var/www/my-project-de/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php(311): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter->filter('????<body style...')
#7 /var/www/my-project-de/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php(391): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->getProcessedTemplate(Array, true)
#8 /var/www/my-project-de/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php(508): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->send(Array, Array, Array)
#9 /var/www/my-project-de/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Mailer.php(84): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->sendTransactional('11', 'sales', Array, Array, Array, '1')
#10 /var/www/my-project-de/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(1354): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Mailer->send()
#11 /var/www/my-project-de/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php(813): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->queueNewOrderEmail()
#12 /var/www/my-project-de/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php(579): Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage->saveOrder()
#13 /var/www/my-project-de/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Checkout_OnepageController->saveOrderAction()
#14 /var/www/my-project-de/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('saveOrder')
#15 /var/www/my-project-de/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#16 /var/www/my-project-de/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#17 /var/www/my-project-de/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#18 /var/www/my-project-de/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#19 {main}
```

Why is the Blocktype invalid?

Answer (score 2):

See this file: `Mage_Germansetup_Block_Imprint_Content`

When Magento doesn't find the right module, it automatically looks into Mage.

However, the Germansetup module is located in the Firegento folder.

First ensure the `Firegento/Germansetup/Block/Imprint/Content.php` exists.

Then looks into the `etc/config.xml` of the module and find the piece of code that declares the block. It should look like this:

```
<global>
        <blocks>
            <germansetup>
                <class>Firegento_Germansetup_Block</class>
            </germansetup>
    </global>
```

Finally look into your email template to check how the block is renderer and ensure the block is declared properly.